# algebra help in AoCP intro to induction

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction

In the introduction of mathematical induction, section 1.2.1 of Knuth's *Art of Computer Programming*, I'm struggling with (4) especially this relation:

$\phi^{n-2} +\phi^{n-1} = \phi^{n-2}(1+\phi)$

Looks like my algebra skills have gone all to rot, if I ever had any, so I am hoping someone can provide a detailed expansion of how these two forms are equal.

Comment: What is $\;\phi\;$ ? The golden mean?

Comment: Distributive property of the real numbers - $a(b+c) = ab+ac$

Comment: @DonAntonio: In this case, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Indeed, though it was mildly interesting...

Comment: I believe $\phi$ is defined as being $(1+\sqrt{5})/2$ so, yes! Though as ShreevatsaR pointed out, it don't matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Distributing and using properties of exponents,

\begin{align*}
\phi^{n - 2} (1 + \phi) &= \phi^{n - 2} \cdot 1 + \phi^{n - 2} \cdot \phi^1 \\
&= \phi^{n - 2} + \phi^{n - 1}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Note that this is a purely algebraic result
that applies to any real, complex,
or other number that system
that 
has an identity,
is distributive
($a(b+c) = ab + ac$),
associative
($a(bc) = (ab)c$),
and commutative
($ab = ba$).

Comment: You don't even need commutativity here. (Arguably associativity either, if you come up with conventions for what $\phi^{n-2}$ etc. mean.)